# After usage is correct or not?

Tags: grammaticality

After traveling for a number of days, their dry rations run out. 
After traveling for a number of days, the fourth youths run out their dry rations. 
Which sentence is correct? Please.

Comment: Neither is quite right. The problem with the first is that the modifier *After traveling for a number of days* does not rightly modify the main-clause subject *rations.* The second would be OK if *fourth* were changed to *four* and *of* inserted before *their dry rations.* (Present-tense *run* instead of past *ran* is OK--historical present tense for storytelling.)

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Without more detail this seems like a case of proof reading, which is [off topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. You also might want to check out our sister site [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/unanswered), but please bear in mind that you would also need to provide more details in your question there (see their help centre for more information).

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatically correct if the verb "ran" is used. It means that after travelling for a number of days, they ran out of their dry rations.

Comment: Technically it's correct if writing in an "odd" tense (present perfect??).  But that would only be assumed if the sentence is in context with others in the same tense.

Answer (score -2):

Both are wrong because you need to use ran instead of run. Also, you have to add "of" after "out" in the second sentence and change fourth to four.

Comment: I disagree. We've no context to suggest [historical/narrative present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) is inappropriate for OP's cited context. Come to that, in principle they could *run out their dry rations* as an established idiomatic usage meaning *presented, displayed*, though I admit it's practically certain that's not what OP intended.

Comment: In addition to FumbleFingers's observation about use of narrative present (a frequent technique among newspaper headline writers), I note that it is not impossible to construct a context in which "fourth youths" is correct. Suppose that the sentences preceding the ones quoted were s follows: "The games commissioner divides the youths into four groups and sends them off into the wilderness. The youths in three of the groups find edible provisions in the wild to supplement the stocks they have taken with them." I do agree that _of_ is needed in the second sentence after _out_ in this scenario.